error after install the official laravel vscode extention
I installed the official laravel vscode extion and I'm getting this error:
[error] /bin/sh: 1: /home/xxx/.vscode-server/data/User/globalStorage/laravel.vscode-laravel/file-downloader-downloads/php-parser-0.1.6: Exec format error

I'm using ubuntu
what is this error and how to fix it?


I tried to install the official laravel vscode extention on ubuntu

Report bug to the extension developer?

better to follow with the official support
https://github.com/laravel/vs-code-extension/issues/11
